# Pass Data From A Model

Tags: c#, rest, model-view-controller, salesforce

I am currently using the Salesforce API populate data.

In my Account controller, I have a method that uses Salesforce Username/Password flow to authorize the API usage and I've attached this so that it does this upon login, this process is fine, it works and I've tested it.

But where my issue comes in to play, I need to access the AccessToken value and ServiceUrl value it generated upon logging in so I can use my, for example, "GetEvents" method in ANOTHER controller.

Currently I am using models, no Data context at all because I don't need it. But if I were to instantiate this model in my other controller, with the AccessToken property, the value will not have been passed through from the controller method that generated this Token.

Keep in mind these Methods work just fine, but I need to be Authorized to view ANY of these events, and if it doesn't have that AccessToken and ServiceUrl from the login method, I can't view any events.

How do I go about this?

METHOD IN HomeController

```
        public async void GetAllEvents()
        {
            TokenModel tm = new TokenModel();

            HttpClient queryClient = new HttpClient();

            string restQuery = tm.ServiceUrl + "/services/data/v25.0/query?q=SELECT+Subject+from+Event";
            Console.WriteLine(restQuery);

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);
            Console.WriteLine(request);

            // Adding the token to the header 
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tm.AccessToken);
            // Return JSON to the caller
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Call Endpoint Async
            HttpResponseMessage response = await queryClient.SendAsync(request);

            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

METHOD IN AccountController

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(AuthRequestModel authRequest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(authRequest);
            }

            if(authRequest == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Authorization is missing");
            }

            var isAuth = Authentication.ActiveDirectoryValidation(authRequest.Username, authRequest.Password);
            if(isAuth == true)
            {
                AuthR().Wait();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }

        // Salesforce Username / Password Validation
        public async Task<string> AuthR()
        {
            TokenModel tm = new TokenModel();
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls
            };

            HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient(handler);

            string clientId = _config.GetSection("Keys").GetSection("client_id").Value;
            string clientSecret = _config.GetSection("Keys").GetSection("client_secret").Value;
            string username = _config.GetSection("Keys").GetSection("username").Value;
            string password = _config.GetSection("Keys").GetSection("password").Value;

            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type","password"},
                {"client_id",clientId},
                {"client_secret",clientSecret},
                {"username",username},
                {"password",password}
            }
          );

            HttpResponseMessage message = await
            authClient.PostAsync("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", content);

            string responseString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseString);

            tm.AccessToken = model["access_token"];
            tm.ServiceUrl = model["instance_url"];

            return tm.AccessToken;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guy but probably you should have a separate class to make new login call or reuse existing session id. Could be static method, could be a singleton pattern (whatever is the right word for it in C#); if statics behave OK being called from another model (thread?). Sharing session id in some global variable probably could work OK too but is bit smelly.

Maybe you have to store the session id somewhere (if you don't have some in-memory cache available then maybe file? database?), encrypted or not.

Battle-tested pattern for logging in to SF would look bit like that

```
do we have cached session id?
    no -> call login()
        -> it worked? great, cache new session id somewhere
        -> didn't work (account deactivated, password expired, network problems) - you have bigger problems your program probably can't recover from nicely, notify user? There's way to reset password via API but it's bit "pro"
    yes -> try to use it
        -> worked? great
        -> error? check the details / HTTP error code and if it's for example session id expired - call new login & handle it like above
```

Depending on authentication method you'll get info when the session id is about to expire (for example 2h from now but every API usage resets the counter). Don't count on that 2h too much. SF admin can terminate your session at any time (preventing hacker access for example). Or there's limit of sessions that can be open for same credentials, used to be something like 5th login() call invalidates oldest session id.